# is there a way to configure and report on finish-to-finish tasks in jira?

Tags: jira

I've configured a task for "Create Welcome Email" with the following AC:

- Identifying a good email API
- Implementing responsive layouts
- Send email from app

I've configured another task for "Specify email requirements" with the following AC:

- Define email layouts
- Define email content

There is a "finish-to-finish" dependency between the 2 tasks because an email API can be identified and test emails can be sent from the app but the emails can't officially be sent from the app in production until the business has officially defined and approved the email layouts and content.

What is a good way to configure this particular dependency in Jira and have it reflected on a Jira report? The native "Linked Issues" dropdown in Jira doesn't seem to have an adequate way to represent this relationship